# what is the reason for using the both static and instance logger variable

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I see below code in one of the class

```
private static final Logger defaultLogger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
private Logger logger = defaultLogger;
```

I would like to know why both static and instace variable are declared? Rest of the class uses the logger variable.
We are using Apache log4j as underlying logging library.

Answer (score 2):

Someone was lazy. The instance in your code refers to the static variable. In other words, there's only one Logger instance (but two referents).

Answer (score 1):

It is to allow you to change the logger later on a per-instance basis. It defaults to the class logger but you can remap it to some other logger, perhaps during certain operations.

Notice that the `logger` variable is **not** `final` for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's an effect of refactoring. Someone sometime in the past planned to use those 2 loggers for a different things and they referred to the different destinations. Then the seconds one was changed to write to the same one.

```
            private Logger logger = defaultLogger;
```

is the least work that needed to be done for that